# Extract the Abstract Syntax tree (AST) of the java call function using python code

Tags: python, java, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using [*javalang*](https://github.com/c2nes/javalang), a [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) package for parsing the [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) code into an [abstract syntax tree (AST)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

This parser treated the call function as a single node in the tree. However, I'm looking to go further in-depth and parse the code of the call function as well. So the tree of the original code will be extended by the tree of the call function. I'm looking for tutorials or books ( with code) that do such analysis for the code.

In other words, I'm trying to inline the function call.

Comment: Not sure to understand. Are you trying to inline the function call?

Comment: @Olivier exactly. Instead of treating the call function as a single node in the tree, I want to replace it with a tree related to the source code of the call function

Comment: That doesn't really make sense as an operation to perform on ASTs.

Comment: In general you can't know which code the method call will use - the class might have subtypes or it might be an interface. For example if the call is to `List.add` it might actually end up being `ArrayList.add` or `LinkedList.add`

Comment: @greg-449 well, in theory, you are right. My case study is a java code related to Functional tests the code is written in a propper way.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm researching to predict the functional test's execution time depending on the source code's structure. We parse the test file ti an AST, but we want to enrich the tree taking into account the calls of function

Comment: Asking for recommendations on books, etc. is explicitly off-topic on this site. I suggest you edit your Question to remove that part.